# Is there an easy way to convert Oracle script to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g, mysql-workbench

I wrote the script below a year ago for a project I was doing in Oracle, I am now trying to duplicate it in MySQL 8.0. Is there an easy way to convert the script so MySQL can run it?

```
DECLARE 
lv_rate NUMBER;
lv_hotel NUMBER;
lv_cat NUMBER;
BEGIN
 FOR A IN (SELECT HOTELID1 lv_hotel, AVG(RATING1) as lv_rate, CATEGORYID1 AS lv_cat
 FROM RATINGS1
 WHERE categoryID1 = 4
 GROUP BY HOTELID1, CATEGORYID1)
LOOP
 INSERT INTO RATINGS (RATING, HOTELID, CATEGORYID)
 VALUES (A.lv_rate, A.lv_hotel, A.lv_cat);
END LOOP;
END;

DECLARE 
 lv_hotel NUMBER;
 lv_pol NUMBER;
 lv_cat NUMBER;
 lv_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
 FOR c IN(
 SELECT INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words) AS lv_count, AVG(b.polarity) AS LV_pol,b.categoryid AS 
LV_CAT, a.idhotel AS LV_hotel
                 FROM reviews a, SeedWords b
             GROUP BY a.idhotel, b.categoryID,INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words))
LOOP
INSERT INTO RATINGS1 (HOTELID1, CATEGORYID1, RATING1)
VALUES (c.lv_hotel, c.lv_cat, c.lv_pol);
END LOOP;
END;


UPDATE RATINGS SET RATING = ROUND(RATING,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of easy.

Is there a way to convert it without spending your time studying the stored procedure syntax, data types, and builtin functions of both Oracle and MySQL?

No.